# Can a function defined by integrals be a piecewise function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, definite-integrals, definition

Suppose we have some monotonically decreasing function $f: \mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$.

Is it possible or valid to define some function $F$ such that:

$$ F(x) = \begin{cases}
            \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt \text{, if } x\geq 0\\
             \\
            \int_{x}^{0} f(t)dt \text{, if } x < 0
&            \end{cases}$$

If it is not a valid way, is there some alternative and valid method of defining $F$ to have a domain over the entire real set.

Comment: $\int_{x}^{0} f(t)dt = 0 - f(x)\cdot x = f(x)\cdot |x|$ is wrong.

Comment: How did you get the idea that $\int_{x}^{0} f(t)dt = 0 - f(x)\cdot x = f(x)\cdot |x|$? It is totally wrong.

Comment: Of course you can define $F$ as you did. $F'(x) = f(x)$ would hold for $x > 0$ only, though. The rest of your calculations makes no sense to me.

Comment: $\int_x^0=-\int_0^x$.

Comment: @Martin R Correct me If I am wrong, but is: $\int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt = f(b) \cdot b - f(a) \cdot a $? Now in this case we have $\int_{x}^{0} f(t) dt = f(0) \cdot 0 - f(x) \cdot x  = 0-f(x)\cdot x= f(x) \cdot (-x)$. Since in this case $x < 0$ it would imply that $-x > 0$. This would imply that $-x = |x|$? Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: @Martin R, Why will $F^{'}(x) = f(x)$ only hold for $x>0$?

Comment: @AndreKleynhans: $\int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt = f(b) \cdot b - f(a) \cdot a$ is definitely wrong. How did you come up with that formula? – The derivative of $\int_{x}^{0} f(t)dt $ is $-f(x)$.

Comment: @MartinR I see my error. Thank you for the help. I am correct to assume that $F$ has a domain in $\mathbb{R}$. I am second guessing everything now.

Comment: I think you are confusing this with integration by parts, which allows you to say that $\int_a^b f(t)dt = bf(b) - af(a) - \int_a^b tf'(t)dt$ (the general relationship is $\int_a^b g'(t)f(t)dt = g(b)f(b) - g(a)f(a) - \int_a^b g(t)f'(t)dt$, which is a consequence of the product rule for derivatives and the fundamental theorem of calculus; here you just substitute $g(t) = t$). Note that $f'(t) \neq 0$ usually so you can't ignore the last integral.